# Word usage in emphatic sense

Tags: word-usage

Consider the sentence: "The need for lawful intervention is being felt more after the terror attacks in November last year."

Shouldn't it be *even more* instead of just *more*?

Comment: Why should it be *even more*?

Comment: The construction of the sentence seems to convey that the need was felt before also and now its even more. Simply more doesn't seem to convey this meaning.

Comment: *More* means that they were being felt before and that feeling has increased.

Comment: It's just that one always reads _even more_ in the newspapers etc.

Comment: 'More' works fine as is. 'Even more' is more intensive. Maybe newspapers like to exaggerate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Even* is an [intensifier](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/intensifiers) modifying *more*, and thus not necessary if there is no need to intensify it. As written, a need existed previously, and since the attacks that need has increased. Perhaps the author seeks to understate— or perhaps they do not perceive the existing need as having been particularly dire.

Consider this statement:

> It was 15°C yesterday, but the need for a coat is being felt more today.

A native of, say, Singapore or Curaçao might ask: don't you mean felt *even* more today? After all, 15°C/60°F would be rather brisk in those countries, so a greater need today suggests the temperature is quite chilly. While I've never met anyone from Nunavut or Sakha, I suspect they would not feel the same way.